# onGUI texture draw eating to much fps

Tags: unity-game-engine

i have a standard 60fps on my iphone 4 when rendering a scene. i then draw 2 textures in onGUI  like this:

```
void OnGUI() 
    {
    GUI.DrawTexture(new Rect(0,0,Screen.width,Screen.height),textureBack);
        GUI.DrawTexture(new Rect(0,0,Screen.width,Screen.height),textureFront);
        }
```

and the FPS drops to ~30fps. The front image needs to have alpha so i set it to be overriden to RGBA 32bit, this image apparently has now 3 mb, the back image is 1.5mb, both have a resolution of 1024x768.

Is there a way to better handle this problem? i want the images to take max 10fps because.. 30fps is absurde!

Comment: A drop of 60fps to 30fps is probably due to vsync. Your original scene is taking < 1/60th to render (and thus allowing 60fps) but if the additional cost of rendering pushes that to just over 1/60th, e.g, 1/59th of a second, the next lower integral frame rate is not 59fps but 30fps.

Anyway, you are probably fill-rate limted. If your main UI texture is mostly transparent, you probably would do better to use more geometry - i.e. dice it into smaller shapes/rectangles and leave out those rectangles that are 'blank'

Comment: @SimonF thanks for the reply! That's what i did, i broke the original image into a lot of other smaller images. I need to implement an eraser, so don't have a lot of blank spaces on my image. Is there anyway that i can improve performance? someone recomended i switch to GUITextures, because GUI.DrawTexture is slow.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a GameObject with the texture on parented to the Main Camera. That way it will follow the camera around like the textures does when you use OnGUI.

Answer (score 0):

Built in GUI in unity performs badly (no draw call batching), you can switch to GUITextures or any other GUI frameworks...

another thing also if you are using the built gui without GUILayout disable it to gain some extra frames.. simply set useGUILayout to false in your start() function